# Separate Editing host for Sitecore Headless application in local docker setup

Tags: jss, experience-editor, docker, nextjs

I am trying to create the separate Editing Host (Next.js) for container setup.

- Sitecore version: 10.3 without SXA
- Sitecore JSS Next.js SDK version: 21.2.4 without SXA Multi-site add-on

For this I performed following steps:

- copy of /docker/build/**rendering** folder and rename as /docker/build/**editingrendering**
- Added the new environment variable in the root .env file

  ```
      RENDERING_HOST=www.myproject.localhost
      #Editing Rendering Host
      EDITING_RENDERING_HOST=editing.myproject.localhost
      EDITING_RENDERING_HOST_INTERNAL_URI=editingrendering:3000
  ```
- in **docker-compose-override** created the new service similar to **rendering** service called **editingrendering**. Using the same code base as rendering service

  ```
  editingrendering:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-editingrendering:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/editingrendering
      target: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-nodejs:${VERSION:-latest}
    volumes:
      - .\src\rendering:C:\app
    environment:
      SITECORE_API_HOST: "http://cm"
      NEXTJS_DIST_DIR: ".next-container"
      PUBLIC_URL: "https://${RENDERING_HOST}"
      JSS_EDITING_SECRET: ${JSS_EDITING_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - cd
      - nodejs
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.editingrendering-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.editingrendering-secure.rule=Host(`${EDITING_RENDERING_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.editingrendering-secure.tls=true"
  ```
- updated the jss app details at src\platform\App_Config\Include\MyProject.config

  ```
    <app name="myproject"
             sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/myproject"
             graphQLEndpoint="/sitecore/api/graph/edge"
             serverSideRenderingEngine="http"
             serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="$(env:RENDERING_HOST_INTERNAL_URI)/api/editing/render"
             serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="$(env:RENDERING_HOST_PUBLIC_URI)"
             useLanguageSpecificLayout="true"
             defaultWorkflow=""
             protectDeveloperItems="false"
             deploymentSecret="$(env:JSS_MyProject_DEPLOYMENT_SECRET)"
             debugSecurity="false"
             inherits="defaults" />
  ```
- in docker-compose-override updated the CM service to pass the new editing rendering host details (value of EDITING_RENDERING_HOST from root .env file with HTTP) RENDERING_HOST_INTERNAL_URI in environment variables

```
environment:
     SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: <license file path>
     JSS_MyProject_DEPLOYMENT_SECRET: ${JSS_MyProject_DEPLOYMENT_SECRET}
     SITECORE_JSS_EDITING_SECRET: ${JSS_EDITING_SECRET}
     RENDERING_HOST_PUBLIC_URI: "https://${RENDERING_HOST}"
     RENDERING_HOST_INTERNAL_URI: "http://${EDITING_RENDERING_HOST_INTERNAL_URI}"
```

After executing the .\up.ps1 script, services are up and running.  The showconfig showing the details as

```
<app name="myproject" sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/MyProject" graphQLEndpoint="/sitecore/api/graph/edge" serverSideRenderingEngine="http" serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="http://editingrendering:3000/api/editing/render" serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="https://www.myproject.localhost" useLanguageSpecificLayout="true" defaultWorkflow="" protectDeveloperItems="false" deploymentSecret="xxx" debugSecurity="false" inherits="defaults" patch:source="MyProject.config"/>
```

*Rendering host url https://www.myproject.localhost/ stopped loading and was working before adding the separate editing rendering host service, and no error in the old rendering host logs.*

Once, starting from scratch, Rendering host (rendering service [www.myproject.localhost](http://www.myproject.localhost)) not loading and page is coming as BLANK or giving error like Bad Gateway.

The page is not loading in Exp. Editor (new editing rendering host url passed like editingrendering:3000 to serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl), and giving error The operation has timed out and CM logs showing :

```
ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `http://editingrendering:3000/api/editing/render`

1260 10:40:07 ERROR The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Exception: System.Net.WebException

Message: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Source: System

   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)

   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)

   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
```

I increased the time to 20000 as per [https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/troubleshooting-jss-next-js-apps.html#rendering-host[…]perience-editor](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/troubleshooting-jss-next-js-apps.html#rendering-host%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dperience-editor) but no luck.

Any other steps, i have to follow to create the separate editing rendering host for my local Sitecore Docker Container setup?